# C#, Resharper, "Possible 'null' assignment to entity" warning when it shouldn't be

Tags: c#, null, visual-studio-2015, resharper, resharper-9.2

I have a method that turns string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string value) into an extension method.

```
public static bool IsNullOrWhitespace(this string source)
{
  return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source);
}
```

After I use this to check for null, Resharper still warns me that the variable  I'm passing as a [NotNull] argument might be null.

```
"Possible 'null' assignment to entity marked with 'NotNull' attribute"
```

If I replace my use (str.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()) with the original (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)), the warning doesn't show up.

Is there a way with Resharper that I can train it to know that my extension method is a valid null checker so that this null assignment warning doesn't show up?

Note:

1. I don't want to hide it with //resharper disable comments everwhere.
2. I don't want to disable it entirely, as it should show up when I'm not null-checking.

Edit:

There's a property in the JetBrains.Annotations NuGet package called ContractAnnotation that does the trick.

```
[ContractAnnotation("source:null => true")]
public static bool IsNullOrWhitespace(this string source)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source);
}
```

This does the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!

There's a property in the JetBrains.Annotations NuGet package called ContractAnnotation that does the trick.

```
[ContractAnnotation("source:null => true")]
public static bool IsNullOrWhitespace(this string source)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source);
}
```

This does the trick.

Comment: That's the ticket. Answer your own question! Good research!

Answer (score 1):

Except, if you want to remove the warning (ReSharper v2016.2), it should be `false` instead of `true` as shown in the answer.

```
[ContractAnnotation("parameterName:null => false")]
```

instead of

```
[ContractAnnotation("parameterName:null => true")]
```

Answer (score -1):

it's because you can still call

```
((string)null).IsNullOrWhiteSpace()
```

and Resharper is concerned.

Rewrite the code as this:

```
(source == null) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source)
```

and maybe it'll stop complaining.

Comment: It still complains in the using code. Actually, when I added used your suggestion, Resharper recommended to "Merge sequential checks," which just removes the first one.

Comment: calling ((string)null).IsNullOrWhitespace() would return false.

Comment: @jack suggest you try it.

Comment: I did try it, that's the results I got. What do you mean?

Comment: @jack, if your Extension function is coded as shown, then there's no way that `((string)null).IsNullOrWhitespace()` can possibly return `false`. That or we live in differing universes.

Comment: Sorry, I meant true. The point was that ((string)null).IsNullOrWhiteSpace() works as intended, so I'm not sure why Resharper would be concerned about it.

Comment: @jack, Resharper is probably concerned about it because it has no idea of the implementation `IsNullorWhitespace` extension method. There may be a `#pragma` or `attribute` you can decorate the code with to tell Resharper to ignore null checks.